# Django save and return object at once (with a custom pk)

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-queryset

I am creating the  object of a model using custom create method `create_actor` like this:

```
class ActorsManager(models.QuerySet):
    def create_actor(self, email,
        actortype,
        locationid,
        primaryphone, actoruniversalid):
        actor = self.model(email=email,
            actortype=actortype,
            locationid = locationid,
            primaryphone=primaryphone, actoruniversalid= actoruniversalid)

        actor.save(using='gpr')
        return actor

actor_entry = Actors.objects.using('gpr').create_actor(email='', actortype=1, locationid = location_entry,primaryphone='', actoruniversalid= new_bluenumber)
```

I am not getting the recently created object in `actor_entry` variable,
may be i am doing something wrong, please help.

I'm using a *before insert* SQL trigger to generate uuid as pk(CharField here) in the database, so the object does have a pk (generated by the database) before its saved.

Actors Model

```
class Actors(models.Model):
    actorid = models.CharField(db_column='ActorID', primary_key=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    actoruniversalid = models.CharField(db_column='ActorBluenumber', unique=True, blank=True, null=True, max_length=254)
    ......
    ......
    objects = ActorsManager.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'actors'
```

Comment: What *are* you getting? Is is a null object or something else?

Comment: Its an instance of the Actors objects but with the fields i have given i.e **email='',actortype=1, actorid(pk here)=' '**. But not the one returned after the save as it should give the pk then.

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: @knbk Model added in the question.

Comment: Only an `AutoField` will [set the pk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys) after saving the object.

Comment: @knbk i generate the **pk** as **uuid** through the _before insert_ SQL trigger defined in the database. So the object gets saved with generated uuid as pk.

Comment: So your db record has a pk. That doesn't change the fact that you're not using an `AutoField`, so the _python_ logic to retrieve the pk is not executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116811/discussion-between-kapil-sachdev-and-knbk).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you created your `actors` table by hand, the `ActorID` will not automatically be set.  Depending on your database backend, `None` may be treated the same as the empty string, and as such could be a valid primary key.  I believe Django takes special measures to update the row if one exists with the same primary key unless you specify [`forceinsert=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update) when invoking `save()`

Comment: Probably better to remove `primary_key = True` from actor id and migrate so that pk is autoincrement integer and created at save

Comment: @joelgoldstick  i generate the **pk** as **uuid** through the _before insert_ SQL trigger defined in the database. So the object gets saved with uuid as pk and is NOT None

Comment: @KapilSachdev: yes, but Django doesn't know that.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, you are right, i was unaware of this fact, until knbk pointed it out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

As @knbk pointed out that only an AutoField can set the pk to an object and so the *pythonic* logic to retrieve the pk is not executed when its not an AutoField and so django doesn't know about it.

After searching the django documentation I found an alternative to AutoField for UUIDs,an [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) which is best suited for my Use Case.

```
actorid = models.UUIDField(db_column='ActorID', primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

So now the django does know of the pk and thus the object is retrieved after being saved.

Thank you all for the help.