# Django form.save() does not return a pk value, when pk is UUID

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I'm running my project on Python 3.7.5, Django >=2.2.8,<3.0.0 and Postgres 12.1
I have implemented 2 models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        'Person', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_column='person_uuid')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    add_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The CreateUser view shown below is for registering new users. This view consists of 2 forms, a user creation form and a person form. Once the user enters their details I want to save the person_form and set the person field in CustomUser to the newly created person. But the value of pk after save is always None.

To work around this, I query the Person model with the matching first_name and last_name and use the UUID from the response. But this is very brittle, as I have other models that use UUID and don't have unique values like first_name and last_name. I wonder if there is a more reliable way of getting the UUID of the form just saved.

```
class CreateUserView(View):
    template_name = 'core/create_user.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        person_form = PersonForm()
        context = {'person_form': person_form,
                   'user_form': user_form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        person_form = PersonForm(request.POST)
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        print('Person form is valid: {}'.format(person_form.is_valid()))
        if person_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
            print('User form is valid')
            person = person_form.save()
            print(f'PK of new person is: {person.pk}')
            p = Person.objects.filter(first_name=person.first_name,
                                      last_name=person.last_name).latest('add_date')

            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.person = p
            user.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully')
            return redirect('login')

        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'person_form': person_form,
                                                        'user_form': user_form})
```

***Note***: I realize that Person and CustomUser can be a single model, but Person is used elsewhere in the database with other entities and needs to be independent of user

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267133/django-save-and-return-object-at-once-with-a-custom-pk) interesting, and also [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#auto-incrementing-primary-keys). It seems you don't get any return because your primary key is no AutoField.